# Mac OS (Xelatex) Throws "Font Cannot Be Found" Error

Tags: fonts

MacOs: Mojave
TexLive: 2020

I need to use a gothic font on the title page. I keep getting the "font cannot be found" error, though the font shows that it is installed in Font Book on MacOs. In the example, if I common out the line(s) referring to AmericanText Regular the text compiles. The font in question is a royalty-free, free font. Libertinus Serif is found with no problem. [image]

This seems to be a common error. How can I fix it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}
\newfontfamily\zmyfont{American Text Regular} 



\title{Some Title}
\zmyfont{whatever}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Bacon ipsum dolor amet ground round sausage leberkas pig porchetta kielbasa boudin   hamburger spare ribs venison. Pastrami porchetta shankle prosciutto tail short ribs salami meatloaf drumstick shoulder t-bone meatball buffalo. Chislic short ribs bacon,   andouille shoulder shankle ham hock salami boudin meatball bresaola. Turducken meatball ball tip pork chop pork belly jerky strip steak t-bone, cow tail ham hock pig. Chuck tenderloin tail, pork loin landjaeger beef ribs fatback doner tri-tip short ribs meatloaf.



\end{document}
```

[image: Showing Font Book title]

[image: Still can't find the font]

Comment: probably the font has a different name. Try variants like `American Text Regular`, or `AmericanText-Regular`, or try  with lualatex (it is less picky regarding names) or try with the filename instead of the font name.

Comment: unrelated it's probably best not to load `xltxtra,xunicode` for most documents these days (showing up in the t3enc file in your log fragment, You really want Unicode not T3 encoded fonts with xetex)

Comment: google suggests `American Text Regular` with two spaces

Comment: XeLaTeX still can't find it, even though it is an installed system font, shows up in Font Book, and the Font Book title is entered correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a comment with picture.

Usually I will go to font book,
select a font,
press Command + i (or the circled `i` on the top right corner),
and copy and paste the PostScript name

[image]